# Illustrator Image Trace results in image disappearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

After selecting the image and trying to Image Trace the image just disappears.
[image]

Comment: It's most likely the **settings** for image trace.. too high of a threshold and art which is overall light in value. Without seeing the settings as well as the artwork, it's pretty impossible to be definitive.

Answer (score 1):

When you do an Image Trace, the default is set to black and white. This means for a colour image containing objects that are blue, the threshold setting is too low for you to see anything, and what you probably want is to change the settings to colour anyway.

1. After doing the trace, click on the Image Trace Panel button in the controls along the top

[image]

2. When the panel opens up, change the Preset to something like *6 Colors* to begin with. You can change the number of colours later

[image]

**Note:** From your screen shot I can see your image is very pixelated, which probably means it's a very low resolution image.  You may need a higher resolution image to get a good trace. Image tracing doesn't work well on very low resolution images.